# Datatables can not be responsive as example

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

i have a trouble with the datatables there.
I trying to add a datatables with responsive as the image
[image]

It's ok when i put it as a separate file but when i add the data from my database, i can not press on the plus icon to show detail about the member as the image

[image]

i just change the data and i don't know why it doesn't work.
Can you help?
This is my code: (i did close php tag for the first open php but i dont know why i can not post it on here)

```
<?php
$stt= 1;
$sql= "SELECT * from users ORDER BY level DESC";
//thuc hien cau lenh voi bien conn lay tu file connection.php
$query= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php echo $stt++?></th>
    <td><?php echo $data["firstname"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["lastname"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["username"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["email"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["phone"]?></td>
    <td>
        <?php
            if($data["level"] == 1){
                echo "Administrator";
                }else{
                    echo "Member";
                    }
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="mem_detail.php?id=<?php echo $data["id"]?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button">Detail</a>

 </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Does anyone has any ideas, please help

Comment: Please write code of your datatable binding.

Comment: check your browser console , there you will find the errors. than remove the errors , or sent here your JS error.

Comment: how can i write code of my datatable binding?

Comment: write jquery code for datatable.

Comment: I can not get your point, sorry for my bad English

Comment: did you mean this one?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>

Comment: please show you jquery code of datatable binding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99286/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-hoang-trung-hiu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code

```
<th scope="row"><?php echo $stt++?></th>
```

to

```
<td scope="row"><?php echo $stt++?></td>
```

change `th` to `td` will fix your problem.